# Add elements in set by user- this integers has to be separated by space not using pressing Enter

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I try to enter elements in sets separated by space.

```
main =set()
size1 = int(input())
for _ in range(size1):
    ele = int(input()).strip().split()[:size1]
    main.add(ele)
print(main)
```

Thes code gives me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 6, in <module>
    ele = int(input()).strip().split()[:size1]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 5 3'
```

And Sorry for my Questioning style. Literally, I don't know how to ask a question.
Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: What integer *should* python give for the input `'1 5 3'`?  `int(input()).strip().split()` tries to convert to an int before splitting!

Comment: Do you need to let the user provide numbers separated by spaces, then add those numbers to a set?  You can write your question in your native language then use a tool to translate it to English.

Comment: It is just a suggestion to get a better answer to your question. Check the following code `main =set()
size1 = int(input())
ele = input().strip().split()[:size1]
for _ in range(size1):
    main.add(int(ele[_]))
print(main)` and let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the input like this:

```
for i in range(size1):
    ele = map(int, input().strip().split())
    for num in ele:
        main.add(num)
```

Comment: Not worked! It give an error - TypeError: unhashable type:'list'

Comment: I missed that you are adding it to a set, check the edited answer.

Comment: Not worked.. EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: Post your complete code and sample input, can’t fix the error with given information.

Comment: I post my whole code. In input I give size of set and numbers for adding in set like this - 3 (in first line size of set) and 1 5 3(try to add three elements in set second line). when I enter elements by pressing 'Enter' then it work , but I want to add them by pressing space.

Comment: Above code works for space separated integers, try the edited code again maybe.